# Getting individual values from a nested list

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to find similarities between multiple (~580) .csv files. The way I want to do this looks like this:

1. Put all the files in a list stored in variable
2. Open each file one by one
3. Split each file so each line is a list
4. Get the header and data from the opened file and store them each in their own variable (headers and filelist)
5. Make each value inside a sublist(?), which stands for a file, unique.
6. Create a loop in which each file is compared to the filelist
7. If step 6 finds values which are similar to the file, print out the name of the file + the value

The filelist (completed step 4) looks like this:

```
[['00000000B847912E,,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,ALG0,,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,<>Z*,,0,1,AUT-ANALYSE,0,0,1,25.10.2017, 09:38:42,0,0,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0', ''], ['00000000B75B90E6,...
```

I'm stuck at step 5. Any idea how I can complete that step?

Current code looks like this:

```
from os import listdir, chdir
path = (r'C:\...')
chdir(path)
files = [f for f in listdir(path)]

class Dataset():

    def __init__(self, files):
        self.files = files

    def openfiles(self):
        self.filelist = []
        self.headers = []
        for file in self.files:
            if file.lower().endswith('.txt'):
                with open(file, 'r') as x:
                    x = x.read()
                    x = x.split('\n')
                    #y = [line.split(',') for line in x]
                    header = x[0]
                    data = x[1:]
                    self.filelist.append(data)
                    self.headers.append(header)

        return self.filelist  

    def uniquevalues(self):
        last = object()
        self.uniquefilelist = []
        self.openfiles()
        for file in self.filelist:
            for line in file:
                for value in line:
                    if value == last:
                        continue

                        self.uniquefilelist.append(item)
                        last = item



        return self.uniquefilelist
```

edit desired output: If I take the list showed before, the desired output would look like this:

```
[['00000000B847912E,1,ALG0,<>Z*,0,AUT-ANALYSE,25.10.2017, 09:38:42,3,''], ['00000000B75B90E6,...
```

edit 2: Edited the post. Commented out y in openfiles() because it was creating a new list for each line in the file. I don't think that this helps my desired outcome

edit 3 Answer Novak: I put it in the code like this:

```
def uniquevalues(self):
        self.uniquelist = []
        self.openfiles()
        for file in self.filelist:
            file = list(set(file))
            self.uniquelist.append(file)      

        return self.uniquelist
```

output is still not unique + it adds '' at the start of each list:

```
[['','00000000B847912E,,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,ALG0,,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,<>Z*,,0,1,AUT-ANALYSE,0,0,1,25.10.2017, 09:38:42,0,0,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0'], ['', '00000000B75B90EB,...
```

Edit 4: Function I wrote:

```
def notonestring(self):
    self.openfiles()
    self.useddata = []
    for i in self.filelist:
        l = i.split(',')
        self.useddata.append(l)

    return self.useddata
```

Input is the list from step 4

Edit 5: Code:

```
for i in filelist:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        l = i[j].split(',')
        useddata.append(l)
```

output(for file 2): `print(useddata[1])`

```
['00000000B75B90E7', '2', '12.04.2017 08:48:00', '01.01.1754 10:48:26', 'LFR\\H.SIEPEL', '156', '62001', '1', '14', '15', 'Field1=0(ABO)', '1', 'ABO', '0', '', '0', '', '1', '0', 'Lefier']
```

One line. It should be 7. It also starts at the second line now instead of the first.

Comment: Could you maybe add example of data and desired output?

Comment: What kind of similarities are you trying to find? For ex: X number of files are a copy of each other, Y number of file contain a specific line or Z number of files contain a specific word etc.?

Comment: @zipa I've edited the post

Comment: @sgarg I'm trying to find values on which I can join in the database. So for example: File A contains xe38023 and File Z contains xe38023 as well, show me that it does

Answer (score 0):

You can just write something like:

```
step_5_list = []
for i in step_4_list:
  for j in i:
    l = list(set(i))
    step_5_list.append(l)
```

This works because set is a data structure that keeps only the unique elements. So you turn list into set, it keeps only unique elements and then you return it back to the list and append to the resulting list.

Also, I see that every sublist starts and finishes with `'`. That means that you have a list which consists of one string. In order to get the list, you should do something like this:

```
res = []
for i in step_4_sublist:
  l = i.split(',')
  res.append(l)
```

after this you should do the part I've written earlier.

I hope this helps you. If it's still not clear, just ask mi in the comment :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've tried your code but it doesn't give the desired result. I've edited the post (edit 3) with the code and output.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer. I hope this works for you now. Just note that it's hard to read the list and such data structures the way you posted it. You should write it with 4 preceeding spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and answer! I made a different function for it doing exactly as you said but I got the a AttributError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Can you just edit your post with the function that you wrote for this and the exact input?

Comment: Done! Not sure what you mean with input though. I'm using the list self.filelist from step 4

Comment: Oh, I see where the problem is. On the end of the first sublist there is a comma and `''`. That means that sublist contains 2 elements. So you have to write: `i = i[0].split(',')`

Comment: Thanks @Novak it works! Now working on getting the 'good' values, e.g. removing all values with len < 3.

Comment: Great :) I would appreciate +1. If you need any more help, just write in the comments here

Comment: Hi Novak, I tried giving you +1 but it won't show. I have a 'bug' with the code you send me. Because I'm doing; l = i[0].split(',') - it is only taking the first line of each file, while I want all the lines. I've tied doing it like this: l = i[:len(i)].split(',') but that gives me the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Use another for loop to loop over the elements in the list

Comment: I don't understand? Could you clarify with a example?

Comment: `for i in step_4_list:
   for j in range(len(i)):
     l = i[j].split(',')`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't give the correct output. I've edited the post (edit 5)